# Facing problem while conversion of Task[] tasks into IEnumerable<Task<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

Error Task[] tasks converison IEnumerable<Task<T>>

```
//await Task.WhenAll(WithMaxConcurrency(tasks,3)); // getting error at tasks conversion
```

```
 var tasks = new Func<Task>[]
        {
            () => jack(),
            () => roy(),
            () => sam()
        };

        await Task.WhenAll(WithMaxConcurrency(tasks,3)); // getting error at tasks conversion
```

```
private static IEnumerable<Task<T>> WithMaxConcurrency<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks, int maxParallelism)
    {
        SemaphoreSlim maxOperations = new SemaphoreSlim(maxParallelism);
        // The original tasks get wrapped in a new task that must first await a semaphore before the original task is called.
        return tasks.Select(task => maxOperations.WaitAsync().ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            try { return task; }
            finally { maxOperations.Release(); }
        }).Unwrap());
    }
```

Want Task[] tasks into IEnumerable<Task<T>>

Comment: What are you trying to do? This method won't restrict concurrency. All tasks are already running

Comment: `Task<T>` inherits from `Task`, not the other way around. You can't take a `Task` and turn it into a `Task<T>`

Comment: Your `WithMaxConcurrency` implementation is functionally identical to `return tasks` but with a slight overhead of taking out and immediately releasing a lock.

Comment: If you want to execute multiple tasks/jobs with a limited DOP there are high-level ways to do it. For example you can use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` or an `ActionBlock` with a specific MaxDegreeOfParallelism parameter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 

var tasks = new Func<Task>[]
        {
            () => jack(),
            () => roy(),
            () => sam(),
            ()=jack(),
            ()=sam()
        };  

How can i perform Parallel.ForEachAsync on my code snippets above, i want break dowk the task into 3 and perform asynchronously

Comment: Note that in *almost* all situations you should be using `await` and not `ContinueWith` to add continuations.  Using `ContinueWith` correctly is much harder in most situations, and I would argue this isn't one of the exceptions.

Comment: What do those functions do? You're describing what you think the solution would look like. What is the actual problem? Do you have 3 completely unrelated tasks? Or do you want to limit eg how many concurrent calls you make to a site or database?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  i want MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 

var tasks = new Func<Task>[]
        {
            () => jack(),
            () => roy(),
            () => sam(),
            ()=jack(),
            ()=sam()
        };  

How can i perform Parallel.ForEachAsync on my code snippets above, i want break down the task into chunks of 3 and perform asynchronously of all the list task.

Comment: Describe how you expect a `Task` to become a `Task<T>`, where do you expect the result to come from if the existing function does not return one (`Task` is basically a `void` function). This is a circle you cannot square. The three functions all have to return the same thing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos therse is list of async task. I want all the task should be run parralely into chunks of 3. When all the task from the list is complete then it will calll the main method to excute

Comment: You've repeated the exact same comment 3 times. That's not what I asked. What do those functions do? It matters. If eg they download stuff, `Parallel.ForEachAsync` would be able to use a single function to process a stream of URLs, 3 at a time. If you need to process the downloaded files you could create eg a pipeline of Dataflow blocks to download the files then process them. Or you could have a single large async method to download and process.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have mutiple asyn method  
    async Task<bool> Method1(string name)
    async Task<bool> Method2(string name)
    async Task<bool> Method3(string name)
    async Task<bool> Method4(string name)
which have different functionality. I want run list of task while breakdown into chunks of 3 i.e 3-3 task run parallely asynchronously

Answer (score -1):

The question seems to be how to throttle the execution of tasks. It's unclear what those tasks do though. .NET has high-level features that allow processing lots of data concurrently, in pipelines etc. One option is to use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` to process a stream of data using a specific number of workers

**Using Parallel.ForEachAsync**

[This example](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/parallelforeachasync-in-net-6) shows how to retrieve Github user bios, 3 at a time:

```
var userHandlers = new []
{
    "users/okyrylchuk",
    "users/shanselman",
    "users/jaredpar",
    "users/davidfowl"
};
 

ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
};
 
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(userHandlers, parallelOptions, async (uri, token) =>
{
    var user = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<GitHubUser>(uri, token);

    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {user.Name}\nBio: {user.Bio}\n");
});
```

This can be used to process a collection of `Func<Task>` calls too, acting as a job queue. That's not as useful as processing a stream of input though:

```
var funcs= new Func<Task>[]
        {
            () => jack(),
            () => roy(),
            () => sam()
        };
 

ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
};
 
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(funcs, parallelOptions, async (func, _) =>
{
    await func();
});
```

`Parallel.ForEachAsync` doesn't return any results. The delegate will have to store them eg in a ConcurrentQueue:

```
var results=ConcurrentQueue<Whatever>();

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(funcs, parallelOptions, async (func, _) =>
{
    var result=await func();
    results.Enqueue(result);
});
```

**Using Dataflow blocks**

Another option would be to use a Dataflow block, eg an ActionBlock to process the data/calls with a fixed DOP:

```
var dop=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
         {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
         };

var downloader=new ActionBlock<string>(async uri=>{
    var user = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<GitHubUser>(uri);
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {user.Name}\nBio: {user.Bio}\n");
},dop);

foreach(var uri in userHandlers)
{
    await downloader.SendAsync(uri);
}
downloader.Complete();

await downloader.Completion;
```

Blocks can return results though and combined into a pipeline of processing steps:

```
var downloader=new TransformBlock<Uri,FileInfo>(DownloadToCsv,dop);
var importer=new ActionBlock<FileInfo>(Importer);

downloader.LinkTo(importer,new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion=true});


foreach(var uri in fileUris)
{
    await downloader.SendAsync(uri);
}
downloader.Complete();

await importer.Completion;
```

In this case, the `downloader` block retrieves 3 files at a time and sends the `FileInfo` object to the `Importer` block. That block imports the files one at a time to the database. All blocks work concurrently, downloading and importing data at the same time.

When all files are requests, `downloader.Complete()` tells the head block we're finished. After that, we wait for the tail block to process all pending work with `await importer.Completion;`

Dataflow blocks can be used as asynchronous work queues too, but that's not as flexible as using them properly:

```
var queue=new TransformBlock<Func<Task<Whatever>>,Whatever>(func=>func(),dop);
var buffer=new BufferBlock<Whatever>();

queue.LinkTo(buffer);


foreach(var func in funcs)
{
    await queue.SendAsync(func);
}
queue.Complete();
await queue.Completion;

if (buffer.TryReceiveAll(out var results))
{
   //Use the results
}
```

Comment: I have mutiple asyn method async Task<bool> Method1(string name) async Task<bool> Method2(string name) async Task<bool> Method3(string name) async Task<bool> Method4(string name) which have different functionality. I want run list of task while breakdown into chunks of 3 i.e 3-3 task run parallely asynchronously

Comment: That's the 7th time you posted the same comment. I posted this answer to make clear *why* I keep asking what those methods really do. You can easily change `Func<Task>` to `Func<string,Task<bool>>`. It may be better to convert them to a pipeline though. In most cases I'd try to create pipelines instead of work queues